# Passing requesting class type to a requested class constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, castle-windsor

Let's say I have a following class:

```
public class Handler
{
    public Type RequesterType { get; }

    public Handler(Type requesterType)
    {
        RequesterType = requesterType;
    }
}
```

which is itself a dependency of another class:

```
public class Controller
{
    public Handler Handler { get; }

    public Controller(Handler handler)
    {
        Handler = handler;
    }
}
```

---

Is it possible to register `Handler` in such a way that when `Controller` is being resolved, the dependent `Handler`'s constructor argument `requesterType` is being assigned with `Controller` type?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Controller>()
            //Component.For<Handler>(), <- this is the essense of my question
        );

        var controller = container.Resolve<Controller>();
        Console.WriteLine(controller.Handler.RequesterType); //Should output Program.Controller
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you talk us through why `Handler` has a `Type` property vs using say generics?

Comment: @mjwills, to be honest, just a matter of convenience. Requires a bit more typing and ponentially error-prone.

Comment: @mjwills, perhaps it depends on a task. For example, this `Handler` class is to be used by a lot of different classes, and I can easily make a copy-paste mistake while copying constructor definition from one class to another forgetting to change `Handler<Controller>` to `Handler<Whatever>`.

Comment: That is fair. If that is a concern, consider adding a unit test to validate that stuff at build time (or on your CI server).

Comment: @mjwills, thanks, will probably have to stick to this solution. Still, I'd prefer to fully delegate this type-detecting work to a machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to handle this would be to make Handler generic:

```
public class Handler<T>
{
    public Type RequesterType { get { return typeof(T) ; }
}
```

Then instead of passing the type in the constructor, you'd pass it as a generic type parameter:

```
public class Controller
{
    public Handler<Controller> Handler { get; }

    public Controller(Handler<Controller> handler)
    {
        Handler = handler;
    }
}
```

Now you can register your handlers per controller in the usual way, and they will resolve for the right type.

You may want to embellish this a bit with interfaces or covariance, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I ended up using generics because I couldn't find any other solution.